# How can I show/solve this equation?

Tags: probability, stochastic-analysis

I need help to prove the following equation.
$X_n$ is an iid random variable, with:

$$\mathbb{P}(X_1=1)=\mathbb{P}(X_1=-1)=\frac{1}{2}$$

Show:

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{M_n}{\sqrt{n}}>x\right)=2\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{S_n}{\sqrt{n}}>x\right)-\mathbb{P}\left(S_n=m_n\right)$$

With:

$$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i,\qquad
M_n=\smash{\displaystyle\max_{j \in \{1,\dots,n\}}}S_j, \qquad m_n=\min\left\{i\in \mathbb{N}:i>x\sqrt{n}\right\}$$

Thanks for helping me with this problem. Everything is appreciated: scripts, useful tips, etc...

With best regards.

Comment: The equation as given is not true for every $x$. Take $x< -\sqrt{n}$ or equivalently $x\sqrt{n}<-n$. Then $P(M_n>x\sqrt{n})=P(S_n>x\sqrt{n})=1$ but $P(S_n=m_n)$ is not necessarily equal to $1$. So the left side is equal to $1$ and the right side equal to $2-P(S_n=m_n)\neq 1$.

Comment: Sorry $x\geq0$ should be useful :)